# Buying New Tefillin during Nine Days / 3 Weeks

Tags: tefilin, three-weeks, nine-days

Is one allowed to buy new tefillin during the 9 days or 3 weeks? Is one then allowed to wear that same new tefillin during the 9 days / 3 weeks?

And if the answer is yes: why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

R. Moshe Feinstein zt"l says ([Igros Moshe, vol. 5 (Orach Chaim part 3), no. 80](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14676&pgnum=388)) that one may buy them even during the Nine Days, "because it is solely for the purpose of a mitzvah." (By contrast, he says that one should not buy a new tallis during this time, because it is a garment and is subject to the same laws.)