# Can one purchase Seforim during the nine days?

Tags: halacha, nine-days

One is not supposed to do any activities that make a person happy during the nine days. See SA Orach Chaim סימן תקנא & Mishna Berurah quoting the Magen Avraham. Is one allowed to buy new Seforim/Judaism related books during the nine days? Would it matter if he doesn't need them for his learning now?

Comment: see related question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9179/buying-new-tefillin-during-nine-days-3-weeks

Comment: Can you clarify by editing the question whether you're asking about Judaism-content books specifically or about books?

Comment: I get a daily halacha email, and this morning's read, "During the Nine Days one is permitted to purchase items which fulfill both of the following conditions: a) items that do not require a beracha of Shehechiyanu or Hatov V'Hamaitiv, and b) items that are not clothing. Shulchan Aruch w/Mishnah Berurah 551"

Comment: @rosends I recommend moving that to answer with providing source links. That answer appears to provide a very nice general rule to deciding numerous items.

Answer (score 1):

The Kovetz Halachos (Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky) pg.175:17 writes that it is permissible to purchase a sefer which is needed during the nine days. However, to just buy a sefer without a specific need is prohibited.

Footnote (reasoning):

[image]

Comment: Lets say it’s reduced price.

Comment: Rav Shmuel Kamentsky holds in a case of a loss,or a sale one can buy it as long as one leaves it alone until after nine days. He also mentions if one is somewhere that only has that item one can purchase it there in order that they do not need to make another trip.

Comment: And how about if it’s an uncommon book which might not be around till after the nine days?

Comment: That's for sure a case of a davar sheavad

Comment: In all sincerity, it seems like -from the material posted in the answer- that “*simchah*” has taken on extreme proportions. If I don’t need an ice-cold caffeine free Frappuccino but I’m in the mood of it and it’ll just make me happy, would that also be prohibited to purchase?

Comment: @sam Doesn’t davar ha’aved apply [only] to (indirect)loss of **money**? This wouldn’t be a monetary loss, only the person would have to wait until it resurfaces.

Comment: Meant davar haavad in a spiritual sense .